# C# Static method call results in error?

Tags: c#, methods, static

In one STATIC class (my helper class named `AutoItX3Delcarations.cs`) i have wrapped up a dll like so:

```
//AU3_API void WINAPI AU3_Send(LPCWSTR szSendText, /*[in,defaultvalue("")]*/long nMode);
        [DllImport("AutoItX3.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static public extern void AU3_Send([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string SendText, int Mode);
```

Basically, creating a static method within a static class.

Now, in my main program execution I attempt to perform this method like so:

```
 AutoItX3Declarations.AU3_Send("Test Text", 1);
```

which, by the MSDN should work...? But it doesn't! I have attempted to search through here and on google for about an hour but can't see why this isn't working.. I am calling the method by using it's class as the location and then the function as brought in by DLL import.

The error i get is `"....AU3_Send(string,int)' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type' "  ...`

But how am i using it as a type?? I thought this is how you correctly call a static method?

Please help :(

Comment: Please post the code *surrounding* your method call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure your method call is within the body of a method? If you could post the surrounding code, that would help.

For example, this should compile fine:

```
static void Foo()
{
    AutoItX3Declarations.AU3_Send("Test Text", 1);
}
```

I suggest you try that, just to confirm that it really *is* the call context rather than the method declaration which is causing the problem (although I fully expect that's the case).

Comment: Wow... I had *no* idea that the method call had to be within the body of a method.. I was just testing it out in the body of my main form class. I moved it over to a method in my main threading class and compiles fine now.... Hmmm seems like an easy mistep and stupid.. sorry all!